# Problems using unetboot to use it in ubuntu??? how comes?

Tags: unetbootin

How to configure these tools to get them properly working ?

the worked on windows now i took another one for linux and ubuntu, and they don´t run the program, How comes?

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong but from what I understand you brought the program 'UnetBootin' from windows yes?

Assuming that I am correct your error may just be that you don't possess the software to use the Windows Application.

The quick fix is to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install Unetbootin
sudo Unetbootin
```

If you are just determined to get that windows copy to work then you would need Wine

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

source: [How-To-Install-Wine](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/128-desktops/805164-wine-1735-released-how-to-install-on-ubuntudebianlinux-mint)

Comment: How do i get in the shell?

Comment: You mean terminal? A hotkey is "CTRL + ALT + T" 
Or you can type in terminal from the system navigation found when you hit the windows key/click the ubuntu logo in the top left